# can't get object from custom javascript object array property using object method

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class with an array property.  I'm created a method on the object to return a specific object from that array.  However it's not working as I expected.  I don't get an error in any browser but when I try to put it into jsfiddle I get back an error saying

Error:
Problem at line 5 character 18: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined
Implied global: Page 1

I have no idea what that means but it's referring to this line

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.containerDivs.length; i++) {
```

Here's the full code.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Why won't the GetContainerDiv function return the dv but later when I iterate through the elements without the function it works fine.  Thanks.

```
Page = function() {
    this.containerDivs = ["div1", "div2", "div3"];

    this.GetContainerDiv = function(obj, divId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.containerDivs.length; i++) {
            if (obj.containerDivs[i] == divId) return d;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

var page = new Page();

var dv = page.GetContainerDiv(page, "div1");
console.log(dv);

for (var i = 0; i < page.containerDivs.length; i++) {
    if (page.containerDivs[i] == "div1") console.log(page.containerDivs[i]);
}
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is `return d` in your `for` loop... where is `d` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.GetContainerDiv = function(obj, divId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.containerDivs.length; i++) {

```
        if (obj.containerDivs[i] == divId) 
                           return d; // D IS NOT DEFINED
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that.  Thanks!  But still, any idea what this error is about?  Even when I fix the "d" error, I still get this error - Error: Problem at line 5 character 18: Cannot set property 'first' of undefined Implied global: Page 1  thanks.

Comment: this works fine,    var page = new Page();

    var dv = page.getContainerDiv(page, "div1");
  alert("dv : " + dv);
    for (var i = 0; i < page.containerDivs.length; i++) {
        if (page.containerDivs[i] == "div1") {
  alert("page.containerDivs[i] : " +page.containerDivs[i]);
  }

Answer (score 1):

The only problem which I found in your script is with the line

```
if (obj.containerDivs[i] == divId) return d;
```

where **d** is an undefined variable. I believe you intend to return **divId**.

Change that statement to **if (obj.containerDivs[i] == divId) return divId;**